Floating label issue with eye toggle in Ionic password input
I’m working on a password field with an eye toggle in Ionic. The issue I’m facing is that the floating label automatically moves to the top even when the user hasn’t entered anything, which is messing up the UI. Here’s the code I’m using:

<ion-input [fill]=“INPUT_FILL_T.OUTLINE” label-placement=“floating” type=“password” [label]=“‘PASSWORD’ | translate” name=“password” [placeholder]=“‘PASSWORD’ | translate” autocomplete=“off” [(ngModel)]=“loginData.password” required>
<ion-input-password-toggle sl

ot=“end”>

Password label should at the placeholder at the start same like username, when user enter in the field it should float to top of the field
i am using this toggle : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input-password-toggle
here is problem :
Password field image
I want the label to float only when the user types in the input. Could someone help me fix this issue?
Thanks!

Facing the same issue, sadly there seems to be no fix yet and it is on the 'todo-list' of the ionic team https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/28665 with ticket FW-5592
